# What is this red number?

Tags: puzzle-quest-2

This red number has just appeared during play. 
What is it and if it's bad how do I get rid of it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stepped on a trap and now your max HP is reduced by 10. IIRC, you have to go back to town and see the priest to get it healed.